Chrome Extension Manifest V3 - Error 'Invalid value for 'content_security_policy' in manifest.json when implementing external scripts
I'm developing a Chrome extension (Manifest V3) and encountering the following error when trying to upload to Chrome Web Store:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "AdBlocker Upsia",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://api.example.com; object-src 'self'"
  }
  // ... other configurations
}

Error message:
'content_security_policy': Invalid value for 'content_security_policy'
Manifest invalid: 'content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions.

I've already:

Verified manifest syntax
Checked Chrome's official documentation
Tried different CSP configurations
Validated JSON structure

What's the correct way to implement CSP in Manifest V3 to allow external API calls while maintaining security standards? Documentation seems unclear about this specific error."
What I've tried:
// First attempt
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://api.example.com; object-src 'self'"
  }
}

// Second attempt
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://api.example.com; object-src 'self'"
}

// Third attempt with host_permissions
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "host_permissions": ["https://api.example.com/*"],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://api.example.com; object-src 'self'"
  }
}

Expected behavior:

Extension should be accepted in the Chrome Web Store
Ability to make secure calls to my external API (api.example.com)
Maintain compliance with Manifest V3 security policies
CSP should work as described in Chrome's documentation

Actual results:

First attempt: Manifest validation error
Second attempt: Error stating that old syntax is no longer supported
Third attempt: Even with host_permissions, still getting invalid CSP error

Additional attempts included:

Validating JSON in multiple online validators
Consulting Chrome's official documentation
Checking GitHub examples
Testing on different Chrome versions (114 and 115)

The extension needs to communicate with our API securely while following Chrome's latest security standards. Any insights on the correct implementation would be greatly appreciated.

It says here that https://api.example.com is not possible.

i put that because i don't have a link for my extension
